# binding the gridview view .....which is in edit template of another 

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I am having a gridview control and in the edit template of the gridview control., inside the edit template  I need another grid view control., I am having a bound field in the second gridview which always binds to the selected value in the gridview 1 .,

So can somebody tell me in which event and all i have to do the databind for the gridview 2.
I am having an sqldatasource for the gridview2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the event you are looking for is "row_command" of your main gridview. in row_command event, you can get your value from the row that you selected, then find your gridview inside your row, and give its datasource.

i cant test it now, but should be something like this

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = MainGridView.Rows[index];
Gridview dv = row.FindControl(“yourGridViewId”);
dv.DataSource = yourdatasource;
```

Comment: can u send me the code for finding the control in the grid view please.,

Comment: the example is just to give you the main idea